# When I declare multiple NGINX server blocks why do they affect each other?

Tags: nginx

I have the following server blocks...

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        include      snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include      snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name  secondave.net www.secondave.net;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

However I would expect this to work...

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        include      snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include      snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name  secondave.net www.secondave.net;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
    }
```

But if I try to do it this way the reverse proxy doesn't work anymore. Why is it requiring the proxy_pass both places?

Here is me trying to call the endpoint without the proxy_pass in the port 80 block as well...

```
[ec2-user@... nginx]$ curl --insecure https://secondave.net
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

Notice the `Welcome to nginx!`, this is not what the proxied site says. When I add it back again I see the expected site again...

```
[ec2-user@... nginx]$ sudo vi nginx.conf 
[ec2-user@... nginx]$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
[ec2-user@... nginx]$ curl --insecure https://secondave.net
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><title>THEJa
```

This is using AWSLinux2023 which I believe is part of selinux and nginx is installed using yum.

### Additional Info

```
[ec2-user@... ~]$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
...
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  secondave.net www.secondave.net;
        return 404;
    }
        
}
[ec2-user@... ~]$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
[ec2-user@... ~]$ curl --insecure https://secondave.net
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.22.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps you're using `http`, therefore you need the proxy on `http`, since a proxy on `https` doesn't proxy any incoming `http`

Comment: Please elaborate "reverse proxy doesn't work anymore". What is the exact request you make, from where and what is the exact result and what is the expected result?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen the expected result would be that 443 proxies but 80 does not. The result is that neither render the proxied endpoint. I will get a curl response for it in a bit.

Comment: @JaromandaX I can confirm I am using https and port 443

Comment: More details added including the curl command showing the https and the response received when the port 80 proxy is commented out

Answer (score 0):

Your `server` block for HTTP doesn't have a `server_name`. Therefore it does not process the request, but the request is passed to nginx `default_server`, which typically shows the page you see.

You should have at least this for port `80`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <hostname>;

    return 404;
}
```

This configuration returns HTTP Not found error code for all failing requests.

Comment: Not sure what you mean the underscore in server name is fine "In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen: " http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Test is added to the post. As expected it isn't working

Comment: The underscore can be used when the `server` block is a catch-all server. However, your configuration does not have the `default_server` attribute in the `server` block, therefore it is not a catch-all server. I don't see how my example is not working - it does not proxy anything, and that is the requirement you have given in your question.